# asp.net - pass in rows to method

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, dto, rows

I have a method in c# like so.

```
public void Save(int id)
{
   SaveImage("first title", "first.jpg", true);
   SaveImage("second title", "second.jpg", false);
   SaveImage("third title", "third.jpg", false);
}
```

So basically what I want to do is make this dynamic so when I call the Save() method I can specifiy what I want saved. Bearing in mind that I may want to call SaveImage as many times as I want and also set the values.

I have looked into DTO (Data transfer objects) but want to know if there are simpler ways to do this. I'm guessing that it might be an array passed in to the Save method and then a for each loop like so..

foreach item in array
{
    SaveImage(item[0], item[1], item[2]);
}

If anyone has any ideas that would be great.

Thanks in advance

Tom

Comment: Why not just call `SaveImage` directly? What are you really trying to do? Is the information about "what to save" supposed to come from the user somehow? What to the parameters to `SaveImage` mean?

Comment: Usually I would like to call Save directly but there is other code going on inside that method that really should only be run once as it's processing an image. I don't want to process the same image multiple times. Basically i'm constrained by the current method. Thanks for your help anyway :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
    public void Save(int id, IEnumerable<ImageInfo> images)
    {
        foreach (var image in images)
        {
            SaveImage(image.Title, image.Name, image.Flag);
        }
    }
```

Where `ImageInfo` is:

```
    public class ImageInfo
    {
        public String Title { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public Boolean Flag { get; set; }
    }
```

Which can be used like:

```
    public void TestSave()
    {
        Save(0, new ImageInfo[] { 
            new ImageInfo() { Title = "first title", Name = "first.jpg", Flag = true },
            new ImageInfo() { Title = "second title", Name = "second.jpg", Flag = false },
            new ImageInfo() { Title = "third title", Name = "third.jpg", Flag = false },
        });
    }
```

Comment: That's what I was looking at before. It seems like a good option to be honest.

Save() is located within a class and TestSave() is located in a page code behind. The only thing I didn't understand was where to put class ImageInfo. I didn't want to create a new class file just for that. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Well, you must not be hard-coding these values. Where do you get these values from in your project? You can use that type instead. And there is really no harm creating a `DTO` like this in your project. Because it's just a `DTO` and has nothing to do with `Business Logic`.

Comment: Ah ok. I like to keep things tidy you see but if it has nothing to do with business logic then it's ok.

I will use this to save out images with the location, name etc specified by user text. Thanks for your help on this.